# jQuery .ajax won't pass the second data value to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

here is my code.

```
$('input[name="add-message-post"]').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'addpost.php', 
        data: { message_name: $('input[name="new-message-name"]').val(), message_content: $('input[name="new-message-content"]').val() }
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $(data).hide().prependTo('#messages').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

if I do `print_r($_POST)` on `addpost.php` it only shows `$_POST['message_name']`

it should pass message_content over as well

Comment: Are you sure `$('input[name="new-message-content"]').val()` returns the expected value?

Comment: wow, I didn't even think to check this. I thought it would just pass a blank value. this was the problem though. `message_content` is a textarea, not an input. sorry guys

Comment: Are you sure the input with name "new-message-content" exists? If it doesn't, then "message_content" will be undefined. Undefined values in the JSON data will not be included in the POSTed data.

Comment: @noypiscripter: The value assigned to `data` is an object, not JSON. If an object is passed, jQuery will call `jQuery.param` to convert it to a query string. However, it seems that jQuery is filtering out `undefined` values from the object at some point, since undefined values don't appear in the query string: http://jsfiddle.net/XkF7a/.

Comment: That's what I was saying, jQuery ajax does not submit `undefined` values in the `data` object.

Comment: @noypiscripter: Well, you mentioned JSON so you could have also been talking about `JSON.stringify` instead (which ignores `undefined` values as well). I just wanted to clarify that.